# Is there any way to view the current sessions when using RedisStore?

Tags: node.js, session, heroku, express, redis

I started using Redis to store my user sessions after realizing that Express sessions are not great for that.

I'm doin it like this:

```
var session     = require('express-session');
if (process.env.REDISTOGO_URL) {
    var rtg   = require("url").parse(process.env.REDISTOGO_URL);
    var redis = require("redis").createClient(rtg.port, rtg.hostname);
    redis.auth(rtg.auth.split(":")[1]);
} else {
    var redis = require("redis").createClient();
}
var RedisStore  = require('connect-redis')(session);

var redisOptions = {client: redis};
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore(redisOptions),
    secret: 'honkydory',
    name: 'honk'
}));
```

My question is, is there any way for me to peek into thge Redis database while it is running? I'd like to be able to monitor if there are users logged in and which users they are. Also I want to make sure that it is creating and maintaining sessions properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) to get the list of session keys, then iterate over those keys if you need to pull in the session data.

For example (untested):

```
function getSessions(cb) {
  var keys = [];
  var cursor = 0;
  (function next(err, reply) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    if (reply) {
      cursor = reply[0];
      if (reply[1].length > 0)
        keys = keys.concat(reply[1]);
      if (cursor == 0)
        return cb(null, keys);
    }
    redis.scan(cursor, 'match sess:*', next);
  })();
}

// ...

getSessions(function(err, keys) {
  if (err) throw err;
  if (keys.length) {
    redis.mget(keys, function(err, sessionDatas) {
      if (err) throw err;
      // keys[0] matches with sessionDatas[0], etc.
    });
  } else
    console.log('No sessions');
});
```

Comment: apparently scan doesn't exist

Comment: It [exists](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/ef1a90642d509ee2724d2b2dd449e041da0210f3/lib/commands.js#L159), it's just not documented. I just installed `redis` from npm and the function is there on the client object.

Comment: perhaps you have an old version installed? I'd compare `npm ls redis` against what npmjs.org shows as the latest version.